# Parse Python Series Object

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to Parse some meta information located in the First row of my XLSX file.

I managed to get only the first row as a df by the following code:

`df = pd.read_excel('MyData.xlsx', nrows=0)`

Printing the `df` gives me the meta information row which looks like this:

`Program=[Retail]   Distributor View=[Manufacturing]    Category=[ALL]  Subcategory=[ALL]   Brand=[ALL] Search for ASIs or Keywords=[ALL]   Reporting Range=[Weekly]    Viewing=[2/7/21 - 2/13/21]  View by=[ASI]`

These are the columns of the dataframe.

I am interested in getting the Date info (`Viewing=[2/7/21 - 2/13/21]`) in a Python variable.

I did this to capture the `Viewing` field:

```
col = df.iloc[:, 7]
```

Now the col object gives me the result:

`Series([], Name: Viewing=[2/7/21 - 2/13/21], dtype: object)`

I want to capture the string: `Viewing=[2/7/21 - 2/13/21]` to parse the 2 dates.

I am trying to do slicing `col[0]`; `col.iloc[:]`

But am unable to capture the string. It says: `Series([], Name: Viewing=[2/7/21 - 2/13/21], dtype: object)`

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to capture the data `Viewing=[2/7/21 - 2/13/21]` as a string variable.

Comment: Please post sample data

Comment: @DGS I have posted the first row entirely. This is the information I am working on. Not sure what do you mean by sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I found what to do.

Since I was getting an empty series, but the name of the Series was capturing my required information.

I needed to use the `pd.Series.name`

Upon doing `col.name`, I could retrieve the string `Viewing=[2/7/21 - 2/13/21]`, which I can parse as a string.